# CMake custom target dependency

Tags: c++, rust, cmake, dependencies

I use rust and c++ in my project, so this project have one c++ target and two rust target, the following is example CMakeLists.txt

```
project(demo)

add_custom_command(... # cargo build crate A # ...)
add_custom_target(A DEPEND binary_A)

add_custom_command(... # cargo build crate B # ...)
add_custom_target(B DEPEND binary_B)

add_executable(C ...)

add_dependencies(A B)
add_dependencies(A C)
```

The dependency relation is right, but when I modify a source file of rust target B, it only compile B and not A

I try to modify as

```
add_custom_target(A DEPEND binary_A binary_B)
```

But unused

Comment: https://github.com/corrosion-rs/corrosion

Answer (score 0):

`add_dependencies(A B)` means that B will be built *before* A. It does not mean A will be "rebuilt". It is only *ordering*.

What does it mean to "rebuilt" a target? Re-link it or recompile all source files, which ones exactly?

If you want executable C to be re-linked:

```
set_property(TARGET C APPEND PROPERTY LINK_DEPENDS binary_B)
```

If you want all source files of C to be re-compiled, then do:

```
foreach(file IN LISTS THE_SOURCE_FILES_IN_C)
    set_property(FILE ${file} APPEND PROPERTY OBJECT_DEPENDS binary_B)
endforeach()
```